# node js mongoose find data from array in collection

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working with node.js and mongoose I am stuck in a problem. My users collection looks like.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("564b6deec50de8d827c0a51a"),
    "email": "ak@gmail.com",
    "ngos": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("564b7527ecc479e4259edff7"),
            "name": "Children trust",

        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("564b79e0ecc479e4259edff8"),
            "name": "Charity Two",
            "location": "Australia"

        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id": ObjectId("564e0a18c8cd4b5420a9250c"),
    "email": "some@gsomel.com",
    "ngos": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("564e0b3bc8cd4b5420a92510"),
            "name": "Charity Two",
            "location": "US"

        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find all the `ngos` whose name is like `Charity` so it should return me.

```
  {
            "_id": ObjectId("564e0b3bc8cd4b5420a92510"),
            "name": "Charity Two",
            "location": "US"

  }
  {
            "_id": ObjectId("564e0b3bc8cd4b5420a92510"),
            "name": "Charity Two",
            "location": "Australia"

  }
```

I tried

```
User.find({"ngos.name": new RegExp(name, 'i')}, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(user);
});
```

It gave me both users with all the data as I am returning the user but if I change `res.json(user);` to `res.json(user.ngos);` I am not getting any response.

How can I retreive those particular ngos whose name matches?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. If you change the response to res.json(user.ngos) it wont work. You should iterate on the user object in you view. Can you post the code to which view you are sending the response to. So that you can iterate on the user object in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex filtering on your final result array as follows:

```
var rgx = new RegExp(name, 'i');
User.find({"ngos.name": rgx})
    .lean()
    .exec(function(err, users) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        var result = users.map(function (n){
            return n.ngos.filter(function(val){return rgx.test(val.name);});
        })  
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 4));
        res.json(result);
    });
```

Check the demo below.

```js
var cursor = [
 {   
  "ngos": [
   {
    "_id": "564b7527ecc479e4259edff7",
    "name": "Children trust",

   },
   {
    "_id": "564b79e0ecc479e4259edff8",
    "name": "Charity One",
    "location": "Australia"

   }
  ]
 },
 {    
  "ngos": [
   {
    "_id": "564e0b3bc8cd4b5420a92510",
    "name": "Charity Two",
    "location": "US"

   }
  ]
 }
];
var rgx = new RegExp('Charity', 'i');
var result = cursor.map(function (n){
 return n.ngos.filter(function(val){return rgx.test(val.name);});
}) 

pre.innerHTML = "result: " + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Comment: The doc says it limits the resulting array I dont want to limit I want all the ngos with that name and if I remove `{"ngos.$": 1, "_id": 0} ` it gave me all the ngos also which doesnot contain the string.

Comment: @singhakash In that case you would need to do some regex filtering on the final array, as in my updated answer.

Comment: thanks it worked for me by removing `[0]` from `return n.ngos.filter(function(val){return rgx.test(val.name);})[0];` because in case I was searching `Ch` its giving 2 ngos not all the 3 ngos.

Comment: @singhakash Awesome! I've updated my answer to reflect this and if you can mark the answer as accepted, that would be great although there are no obligations in doing so, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
User.find({"ngos.name": new Regex(name, 'i')},{'ngos':1}).exec(function(err,data){
    if (err) throw(err);
    res.json(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this way in mongoose

you getting res is Array so use "forEach"

```
User.find({'ngos.name':new RegExp('name', 'i')}, {'ngos':1},function(err,users){
users.forEach( function(user) {
    user.ngos.forEach( function(nom) {
        console.log( nom );
    })
} );
```

})

just try this way in mongodb

```
db.user.find({'ngos.name':new RegExp('name', 'i')},{'ngos':1}).forEach( function(user) { 
user.ngos.forEach( function(nom) { 
    print( nom );
    })
} )
```

I think this help to u !